# Univalence for non-normal functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking for univalence properties of non-normal functions, i.e. $f(0) \neq 0$ and $f'(0)=1$. Does anybody know how to study this? Actually, I fancy doing the constraint on the transport of such functions.

Comment: $f-f(0)$ is normalized and still univalent so all usual stuff applies to it